# lightbox in html 5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have made an application in which i had made a jigsaw puzzle . The puzzle is working but I want to show light box effect. I have got examples on web which show the lightbox on click of a link but I want to use it when my game is over.. could someone explain how to do it preferably with an example.....

Comment: show you code so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to javascript function when game over

```
document.getElementById("yourlightBoxContent").style.display='block';
document.getElementById("opacityless").style.display ='block';
```

and css of opacityless

```
#opacityless{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

as seen on here http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/